# Which is the best DB to save heirarchial data(Tree )

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, redis, database, nosql

Which is the best way to store heirarchial data. 
eg: An employee has worked at several companies. At each company, he had worked at several projects. At each project he has worked with different modules. Employee has attended different colleges. At each college he has different subjects. etc

If I have to use a Relational DB, I would end up creating tables like Employee, Company, Project, Module, College etc.

I would prefer that if I have the root node like `employee`, I could call something like `employee.save` which should save the whole tree and also if I retrieve the root node, it should retrieve the whole tree structure.

I know that nosqls like **Redis** and **MongoDB** have this ability. Recently I also heard about **neo4j**. So I am confused which one to use. These data is just profile info of users(shown only upon request) so it dosent have to be cached for performance. Also it needs to store profile info of millions of users probably.

In my project, I am planning to use mysql as primary database and Redis for caching the database  search results. But since, profile info dosent have to be cached, I am reluctant to store it using Redis. 
So please let me know which is the best way to store it. Should I use another DB like Mongo etc, or New4j or just go with Redis.... or even mysql?

Comment: Your question is a bit off-topic, but you can read http://neo4j.com/developer/graph-db-vs-rdbms/, it should be helpfull

Comment: Have a look at alternatives (under graph database section)  at : http://www.infoq.com/articles/graph-nosql-neo4j

Comment: What language are you using ? That's also to consider and what format of data ? JSON

Comment: @Arun Satyarth Does my answer help ? If yes then please accept it otherwise ask away if anything is unclear

Comment: Thanks Basit for the answer. I have decided to proceed with Relational DB itself as NOSQL seems a bit too much for the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Thats a good choice. Remember even in BigData, subset of data on which BI is visualised is *usually* shown using a relationalDB (Data marts) since it surpasses NoSQL when complex fetch queries are required. For performance use NoSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How graph databases and other NoSQL/Relational databases differ is how they can fetch information and how they scale.

NoSQLs usually are bad in fetching relational information because of the query format. Graph solve those but might be an overkill for your project.

**SQL syntax:**

```
SELECT person, SUM([score][1]), AVG(score), MIN(score), MAX(score), COUNT(*) 
FROM demo 
WHERE score > 0 AND person IN('bob','jake') 
GROUP BY person;
```

**Mongo / NoSQL format:**

```
db.demo.group({
    "key": {
        "person": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "sumscore": 0,
        "sumforaverageaveragescore": 0,
        "countforaverageaveragescore": 0,
        "countstar": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        prev.sumscore = prev.sumscore + obj.score - 0;
        prev.sumforaverageaveragescore += obj.score;
        prev.countforaverageaveragescore++;
        prev.minimumvaluescore = isNaN(prev.minimumvaluescore) ? obj.score : Math.min(prev.minimumvaluescore, obj.score);
        prev.maximumvaluescore = isNaN(prev.maximumvaluescore) ? obj.score : Math.max(prev.maximumvaluescore, obj.score);
        if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.countstar += true.length;
        else prev.countstar++;
    },
    "finalize": function(prev) {
        prev.averagescore = prev.sumforaverageaveragescore / prev.countforaverageaveragescore;
        delete prev.sumforaverageaveragescore;
        delete prev.countforaverageaveragescore;
    },
    "cond": {
        "score": {
            "$gt": 0
        },
        "person": {
            "$in": ["bob", "jake"]
        }
    }
});
```

Source: [QueryMongo](http://www.querymongo.com/)

I think you should pick Relational Databases or preferably postgresql because storing and fetching information using an SQL will be better and less hassle.

Scaling out is not a problem for you to consider right now in my opinion, if it is you can always pick in-memory distributed caches.